# Use C# exe to modify resources of a different C# exe

Tags: c#, resources, .net-assembly

**Solved! See below.**

I have 2 C# applications. Application a is supposed to modify the internal resources of application b. Application b is supposed to do something with its (modified) resources when executed.

How can I accomplish that?

Here is what I tried:

```
public static void addFileToResources(string dest, string src)
{
    Assembly a_dest = Assembly.LoadFile(dest);

    using (Stream s_dest = a_dest.GetManifestResourceStream("Elevator.Properties.Resources.resources"))
    {
        using (ResourceWriter rw = new ResourceWriter(s_dest))
        {
            byte[] b_src = File.ReadAllBytes(src);
            rw.AddResource("target", b_src);
        }
    }
}
```

I get a `System.ArgumentException` with `The stream is readonly.` on `System.Resources.ResourceWriter..ctor(Stream stream)`

**EDIT**
Since that does not seem to be possible with .net resources: Is there any other way?
I want to produce a single file (namely the exe of application `b`) which is executable and can work with the data (stored in the exe) that is given prior to execution from application `a`. Preferably without having to actually compile `b` in order to give it the data. 


Assumptions in order to make it a little easier:

- `a` is always executed before `b`
- `a` is only executed once
- both applications are written by me

**Edit - Sollution**
Since it is not possible to accomplish that via resources I used the following workaround:
Apparently you can append ANYTHING to an exe file and it will still be executable, so here is what I came up with:

```
public class Packer : IDisposable
{
    // chosen quite arbitrarily; can be anything you'd like but should be reasonably unique
    private static byte[] MAGIC_NUMBER = { 0x44, 0x61, 0x6c, 0x65, 0x6b, 0x4c, 0x75, 0x63 };

    private Stream inStream;

    public Packer(string filename, bool openReadonly = false)
    {
        // The FileAccess.Read is necessary when I whant to read from the file that is being executed.
        // Hint: To get the path for the executing file I used:
        // System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location
        inStream = File.Open(filename, FileMode.Open, openReadonly ? FileAccess.Read : FileAccess.ReadWrite, openReadonly ? FileShare.Read : FileShare.None);
    }

    public byte[] ReadData(int index)
    {
        byte[] mn_buf = new byte[MAGIC_NUMBER.Length];
        byte[] len_buf = new byte[sizeof(Int32)];
        int data_len = 0;
        inStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.End);
        for (int i = 0; i <= index; ++i)
        {
            // Read the last few bytes
            inStream.Seek(-MAGIC_NUMBER.Length, SeekOrigin.Current);
            inStream.Read(mn_buf, 0, MAGIC_NUMBER.Length);
            inStream.Seek(-MAGIC_NUMBER.Length, SeekOrigin.Current);
            for (int j = 0; j < MAGIC_NUMBER.Length; ++j)
            {   // Check if the last bytes are equals to my MAGIC_NUMBER
                if (mn_buf[j] != MAGIC_NUMBER[j])
                {
                    throw new IndexOutOfRangeException("Not enough data.");
                }
            }
            inStream.Seek(-sizeof(Int32), SeekOrigin.Current);
            inStream.Read(len_buf, 0, sizeof(Int32));
            inStream.Seek(-sizeof(Int32), SeekOrigin.Current);
            // Read the length of the data
            data_len = BitConverter.ToInt32(len_buf, 0);
            inStream.Seek(-data_len, SeekOrigin.Current);
        }
        byte[] data = new byte[data_len];
        // Read the actual data and return it
        inStream.Read(data, 0, data_len);
        return data;
    }

    public void AddData(byte[] data)
    {
        // append it
        inStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.End);
        inStream.Write(data, 0, data.
        inStream.Write(BitConverter.GetBytes(data.Length), 0, sizeof(Int32));
        inStream.Write(MAGIC_NUMBER, 0, MAGIC_NUMBER.Length);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        inStream.Dispose();
    }
}
```

If you want to use this snippet go ahead but note that if you add data to a file the indexes are in reverse order when retrieving:
Let's say you write data set A first and then data set B, if you read the data later B will have the index 0 and A the index 1.

Comment: Have you verified that you pass non-null to constructor of `ResourceWriter`?

Comment: Two problems.  You didn't guess at the resource stream name correctly, that's what caused the exception.  And the more severe one you'll run into when you fix that problem, resources are read-only after they are embedded in a .NET assembly.  Rebuilding the executable file is not practical.

Comment: Well... damn. Thanks anyway!

Comment: You have to use external resource file. If `b` is your application, then you could implement own resource manager to load external resource-file *if it exists* or use build-in otherwise.

Comment: That was what I wanted to avoid. I wanted to have it all in one single file.

Comment: If you're willing to use 2 files, I'd recommend looking at the settings support.   The .config files are just XML files and there is nice support in .NET for getting settings, changing them and saving the changes.

Comment: I tried your approach (appending stuff to the file) but it triggers antivirus false-positive alarm, which is a bummer if you're creating commercial product. Ended up using Mono.Cecil. It actually quite simple: you add a Nuget reference to MonoCecil, then write 4-5 lines of code to modify an embedded resource.

Answer (score 4):

Based on your assumptions you can update/add resources of your executable using **Mono.Cecil** library

Here are three essential methods for Resource Manipulation using Mono.Cecil:

```
    public static void ReplaceResource(string path, string resourceName, byte[] resource)
    {
        var definition =
            AssemblyDefinition.ReadAssembly(path);

        for (var i = 0; i < definition.MainModule.Resources.Count; i++)
            if (definition.MainModule.Resources[i].Name == resourceName)
            {
                definition.MainModule.Resources.RemoveAt(i);
                break;
            }

        var er = new EmbeddedResource(resourceName, ManifestResourceAttributes.Public, resource);
        definition.MainModule.Resources.Add(er);
        definition.Write(path);
    }

    public static void AddResource(string path, string resourceName, byte[] resource)
    {
        var definition =
            AssemblyDefinition.ReadAssembly(path);

        var er = new EmbeddedResource(resourceName, ManifestResourceAttributes.Public, resource);
        definition.MainModule.Resources.Add(er);
        definition.Write(path);
    }

    public static MemoryStream GetResource(string path, string resourceName)
    {
        var definition =
            AssemblyDefinition.ReadAssembly(path);

        foreach (var resource in definition.MainModule.Resources)
            if (resource.Name == resourceName)
            {
                var embeddedResource =(EmbeddedResource) resource;
                var stream = embeddedResource.GetResourceStream();

                var bytes = new byte[stream.Length];
                stream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);

                var memStream = new MemoryStream();
                memStream.Write(bytes,0,bytes.Length);
                memStream.Position = 0;
                return memStream;
            }

        return null;
    }
```

You can use `GetResource` method to retrieve current resource stream (Writable),

using `ResourceWriter`, `ResourceReader` or `ResourceEditor` classes you can read/write or modify current resource or create a new resource, then simply put it back in the executable by calling `ReplaceResource` or add it as a new one by calling `AddResource`

Here is an example of replacing an image in resource (by creating a new resource from scratch):

```
            var ms = new MemoryStream();
            var writer = new ResourceWriter(ms);
            writer.AddResource("good_luck",new Bitmap("good_luck.png"));
            writer.Generate();   
            ReplaceResource(@"my executale.exe", "ResourceTest.Properties.Resources.resources",ms.ToArray());
```

you can obtain Cecil through `PM> Install-Package Mono.Cecil` nuget.