# Change settings in windows forms app using a separate exe

Tags: c#, winforms

I am giving my application to a client. The settings for the application are stored in `settings.settings`, using `internal` access modifier. How can I make a separate `exe` to change those in the clients computer?

Example:

My project generates a `foo.exe` file when building i need a `foosettings.exe` file such that only i can change the settings for foo.exe.

Does anyone have a clue as how to achieve this?

Here's what I am trying to do, I need to save some variables to my application which can be changed later using another exe. I cannot use app.config as those variables in app.config can easily be edited by the user. I only want myself to be able to change those values without diving into the code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use C# exe to modify resources of a different C# exe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26123494/use-c-sharp-exe-to-modify-resources-of-a-different-c-sharp-exe)

Comment: @AedvaldTseh the question here asked is specifically related to settings file while the duplicate you suggested is for resources and not for `settings.settings` file.

Comment: You can use `cecil` also to modify your `settings.settings`-class.  Read doc: https://github.com/jbevain/cecil/wiki/HOWTO

Comment: Please ask about the problem you are trying to solve, rather than your proposed solution. This is most likely an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info).

Comment: @IInspectable as suggested I did edit my answer. I am not so used to posting here in stackoverflow please suggest me if any problems. Thanks.

Comment: You have merely reworded your proposed solution without explaining the problem. What are you really trying to accomplish? Please describe that in the most abstract way possible.