# How to programmatically create a self extracting archive?

Tags: c#, self-extracting

I was trying to create a utility that generates an self extracting executable, containing a pregenerated executable and a dynamically generated text file.

I have looked, i may be looking with the wrong keywords, but i have not been able to find anything that would help.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, please read about how to ask questions here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Try to include some of the work that you have done so far, and describe more precisely the problem that you're facing

Comment: You can probably append whatever you want to an exe and it will work

Comment: is there an api to read and write from the executable?
if so i didnt find it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Quick-n-dirty way**

You can append whatever you want to an exe and it will work. So you have your pre-made fixed exe unpacker. You append to it an easily-to-find byte sequence, then you append the file. Or better, you append the file to the stub and then append the length as an `int64`. So in the unpacker you take a look at the last 8 bytes, see how much big is the payload, then you read the payload. No magic sequence necessary. See [appending data to an exe](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5795446/613130) for some suggestions.

**Better way**

You use [mono.cecil](https://github.com/jbevain/cecil) to modify the exe stub and add as a resource the compressed content. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26143978/613130) there is a question about the argument.

Comment: Thanks, looks like that should work